# super().__init__() in a base class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I thought I understood the role of **super** in traversing the MRO but I ran across a python file at my job that contains:

```py
super().__init__() # no parameters
```

in a base class __init__() and I can't ask the original author.  This is in a piece of python3 code but I don't know what version was running when it was originally added.

I would think this would just do nothing or at worst call Object.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods

Comment: I thought I had read that post completely including the refenced articles.  I still don't understand the use case of a base class calling super explicitly. (in python 3)

Comment: I think the point is 3.x python lets you use more of boilerplate implementation then explicitly calling the inherited class.